# Spring boot overriding default 404 exception handling

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have found a lot of questions and answers around this but it seems no matter what I do I cannot bypass the default white label app page for 404 errors. Using boot version 1.4.x

What I am doing is in my application.yml:

```
spring:
   mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
```

Then defining my own Subclass of `ResponseEntityExceptionHandler` annotated with `@ControllerAdvice` where I stick in
 my overridden `handleNoHandlerFoundException`

```
    @ControllerAdvice
public class ThisIsNotWorking extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {

    @Override
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(final NoHandlerFoundException ex,
                                                                   final HttpHeaders headers, final HttpStatus status,
                                                                   final WebRequest request) {
        logger.info(ex.getClass().getName());
        final String error = "No handler found for " + ex.getHttpMethod() + " " + ex.getRequestURL();
```

^^only a snippet above not all the logic.

But when I navigate to a bad route for my boot app I get json in browser with error.  What else do I need to do? Ultimately I want to handle these 404s in a custom way for my app.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that 404 errors can happen both for a bad URL and a resource not found in the database. Do you know which one you are encountering?

Comment: good point I don't want to catch exceptions when my controllers return 404 but i specifically wanted to catch when you go to a mapping not defined by any request mapping.

Comment: are you trying to return a json response, or a custom white page error?

Comment: i honestly want to catch the 404 and note where they were trying to go and then redirect them to page inside front end app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I do I cannot bypass the default white label app page for 404
>   errors

Basically, to handle whitelabel error (`404`) pages, you can simply use the `addErrorPages` inside `customize()` from `EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer` and handle `404` errors as shown below (you don't need `@ControllerAdvice` `handleNoHandlerFoundException()` method from your code):

```
@Component
public class CustomizationBean implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        container.addErrorPages(new ErrorPage(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND,
                                                   "/YOUR_PAGE.html"));
    }
}
```

Comment: do you have to do anything special for that to be picked up? I can navigate to the path I provide to ErrorPage but if I go to `/myapp/badpath` i still get whitelabel page

Comment: nothing special, you need to ensure that this class's package is being scanned (`@Componentscan`) by Spring container

Comment: So I think I found my answer here https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/7653 which is what I am fighting with but will accept your answer because it is valid just not for my situation

Comment: thanks, I am not sure where is the issue, but works fine for me

Comment: You would need to have restful services along with using default resource handler to serve up static resources and swagger. The default resource handler will handle the 404 no matter what way you try to customize error/exception handling . The issue has a test project to recreate